# Best AJAX TreeView

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, treeview

What are some of the better AJAX Treeviews out there that support asynchronous JSON loading.

YUI TreeView seems nice, but bloated with tables, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[jQuery TreeView plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview) it's really good and it haves very nice [asynchronous](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/async.html) [JSON](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/source.phps) loading capabilities...

[ExtJS TreeView Component](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/reorder.html), also great, multi-level asynchronous loading, excelent for large trees.

Comment: I think this treeview only supports asynchronous loading of leafs.  Which may be an issue, if your tree is large.

Comment: Yes, I found the ExtJS Treeview to have better asynchronous loading at many levels http://tinyurl.com/yp49hy

Comment: Shield UI's TreeView is another powerful component, supporting a large variety of data source loading: https://demos.shieldui.com/web/treeview/remote-data

Answer (score 6):

I suggest DHTMLX Tree:

- Cross Browser
- AJAX Support
- In-line node editing
- Drag-n-drop capabilities
- *Smart Rendering - allows avoiding performance problems in trees with great number of nodes per level.
- Rich Client API
- Special techniques implemented into the component make loading of really big trees fast and effective.
- Advanced drag-and-drop makes it possible to drag items not just within one tree, but between different ones (even if trees are located in different frames or iframes).

You can try this functionality right now:

[Live Demo](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/index.shtml)

Comment: We use DHTMLX Tree and that is not as fast as they said. It's response is too slow(2 seconds) with 1000 child elements with checkboxes to select a single checkbox.