# TreeView in all browsers using JQuery instead of VBScript in ActiveX Control

Tags: jquery, ms-access, vbscript, treeview, activex

There is a TreeView which our team has been using now for three or four years which provides our Internet Explorer users the ability to simply view data from both an MS Access database and MSSQL 2005 Server in one TreeView list.

Since the development of this, we have a dilemma forming. The users are beginning to be allowed to use Google Chrome and Firefox which was not included in the original use case and are not compatible with the TreeView ActiveX control this object is coded in outside of Internet Explorer. I believe the original idea for this came from [this type of Windows Common Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/GUI_JScript_VBScript.aspx?display=Print).

**What would be a simple alternative to making this possible using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or another technology provided the current constraint of having no server side scripting available**?

Again, the aim here is to make it compatible with most of the major browsers.

Note: I have attempted to get server side scripting available and this is not an option for this project. So, answers should *not* target using `JSP`, `PHP`, `ASP`, etc... Instead the attempt here is to figure out a way to do this **using a local file on a shared network**.

And yes, I know the security vulnerabilities involved in this type of setup... regardless, this has been the direction.

For example, here is the object in use:

```
 <body onload="SetupPage()">
      <object classid="CLSID:C74190B6-8589-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628" id="MainTree" width="100%" height="290" style="font-family: times new roman; font-size: 16px; Visibility: visible">
        <param name="Style" value="7">
        <param name="_ExtentX" value="5292">
        <param name="_ExtentY" value="10583">
        <param name="_Version" value="393217">
        <param name="HideSelection" value="0">
        <param name="Indentation" value="767">
        <param name="LabelEdit" value="0">
        <param name="LineStyle" value="1">
        <param name="PathSeparator" value="\">
        <param name="Sorted" value="0">
        <param name="Checkboxes" value="0">
        <param name="FullRowSelect" value="0">
        <param name="HotTracking" value="1">
        <param name="Scroll" value="1">
        <param name="SingleSel" value="0">
        <param name="ImageList" value="ImgList">
        <param name="BorderStyle" value="1">
        <param name="Appearance" value="1">
        <param name="MousePointer" value="0">
        <param name="Enabled" value="1">
        <param name="OLEDragMode" value="0">
        <param name="OLEDropMode" value="0">
      </object>
      <object classid="CLSID:2C247F23-8591-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628" id="ImgList" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden"></object>
  <IFrame id="PrtFrame" style="width: 0px; height: 0px">
  </IFRAME>
 </body>
```

After this object is placed in the body of the web page a call to some VBScript allows for populating this object using something like the following:

```
 <script language="vbscript">

    Sub SetupPage()

        Call MainTree.Nodes.Clear
        Call PopulateImageList
        Call PopulateTree

    End Sub

    Sub PopulateTree()

        Dim rs       ' RecordSet
        Dim i        ' Index
        Dim ndParent ' Parent Node

        ' Assign the main html form to a variable xfrm
        Set xfrm = document.MainForm

        ' Setup a connection with the Database
        Set AccessConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        AccessConn.open AccessConnectionString
        strSQL = "SELECT..."
        Set rs = AccessConn.Execute(strSQL) 

        ' Manually set the parent nodes
        i = 1
        Set ndActive = MainTree.Nodes.Add(, 2, "IDC" & i, "Active", ImageIndex("active"))

        ' Move one forward, since the parent node was set manually
        i = i + 1
        Do While rs.EOF = False

            ' Add the detail to each parent node for each record returned...
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        ' etc...
    End Sub

    Sub PopulateImageList()

      Dim lst
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(1,"header",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\header.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(2,"hold",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\hold.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(3,"reviewed",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\reviewed.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(4,"completed",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\completed.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(5,"rejected",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\rejected.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(6,"printed",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\printer.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(7,"active",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\active.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(8,"archived",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\archived.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(9,"emailed",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\emailed.gif"))
      set lst = ImgList.ListImages.Add(10,"assigned",LoadPicture(DirectoryPath & "TreeImages\assigned.gif"))

    End Sub
 </script>
```

Once data is available in the source database, all the user needs to do is open the local file on the shared network and they see something like the following:
[image: TreeView Picture Example]

Any ideas or methods for accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see nothing specific to MS-ACCESS in this question. Why is the tag there?

Comment: A solution needs to be capable of linking to the MS Access database as well as MSSQL 2005 database since these both need to work together to provide a client only option.

Comment: I found this plugin which somewhat does what I am looking for, but still has the same issue of only working in IE. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ACCESSdb

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at the problem from different angle... Forget about accessing database from the client-side [JavaScript]. Than what? Just use SQL Server as a web server to pull the data. It is called [HTTP End Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). This way you can implement data access logic on the SQL Server side (including to MS Access through any of the available interfaces). So, now SQL Server's web service returns data that can be manipulated on the client-side (AJAX) with jQuery ([read this for some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220754/best-ajax-treeview)).

Here are some links I found for the End Point part:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-endpoints-soup-to-nuts/

http://mscerts.programming4.us/sql_server/sql%20server%202008%20%20sql%20server%20web%20services%20-%20building%20web%20services%20(part%201).aspx

I have never implemented SQL Server End Point, so cannot tell if this is easy or not. However, I did similar in [InterSystems Cache database](http://www.intersystems.com/cache/index.html) and that worked very good.

This is how I see it anyway...

P.S.
I am a little confused with your local file approach

Comment: To clarify, my local file approach is due to a restriction which does not allow for any server side scripting. In other words, there is no available option of running this code using a web server like Tomcat/Apache/IIS/etc... Therefore my solution will be limited to something that can be run on the end users desktop. I prefer to keep the solution in a browser as to avoid having to install an executable on every users desktop. So far, I have been able to accomplish this using VBScript and a TreeView object available in IE browsers, but can't find an alternative to this using other technologies.

Comment: Also, one other constraint is the target solution utilizes MSSQL 2005 for which I only have read access to and a DBA administers for which I have little control over the environment.

Comment: Well, you cannot access database or local file system directly from JavaScript. Period. And, number of up-votes for your question suggests I am not alone to be surprised to see a simple pure client-side answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use Access to handle data binding and then use a web browser control (which is Internet Explorer) that is filled dynamically with the required content.  Using document.write you can fill all the content without having to actually create any HTML/JS/CSS on the host machine.  For images you could just embed the DataURIs.

You can bind events as required for user interaction, it is not pretty but assures a controlled environment (you force them to use IE without giving them any source code) and doesn't require special database interaction (as MS Access does all that for you).

MSDN has several articles on the control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=vs.85).aspx.

I'm active duty Air Force working on a "web application" for a unit in Europe with very similar restrictions.  What I ended up doing is using MS Access to launch IE and intercept Navigate2 events for processing.  On the web side I have a sort of jQuery-based templating language I'm building to handle all the SQL fun.  This allows me to write the app entirely in HTML/JS/CSS while Access handles the actually JET binding.  It's still in development but when I'm done I'll slap a C++ launcher I've written so the user will run my EXE from the network that will run an invisible instance of Access and the user will only see the IE instance and application.

https://github.com/jeff-mccoy/EET-Scenario-Builder

Comment: Quite well actually.  I'm working on a couple other projects based on the same codebase and will soon post a new github project for that.  I had to make the project private because of some data the Air Force didn't wan't me sharing.  Access returns JSON and I'm slowly converting the templating portion into RESTful-looking requests as I transition from a client side app to client/server (.Net/SQL) app with mostly the same code. We're now testing this app at several bases in Europe.

Comment: Docs aren't complete but I finally have the github site up with examples:  https://github.com/jeff-mccoy/Access-Web-Viewer.  I have now used the library for several new internal projects.